# Looping over a list to find a match for another list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, select, iteration

Let's say have a list like this:

```
[[t[0] for t in tagger.tag(s)] for s in corpus.sents()[:5]]
```

Looks like this:

```
[['1'], ['Hermann', 'Hesse', 'Der', 'Steppenwolf'], ['Erzählung'], ['Vorwort', 'des', 'Herausgebers'],
['Dieses', 'Buch', 'enthält', 'die', 'uns', 'geblichenen', 'Aufzeichnungen', 'jenes', 'Mannes', ',',
'welchen', 'wir', 'mit', 'einem', 'Ausdruck', ',', 'den', 'er', 'selbst', 'mehrmals', 'gebrauchte', ',',
'den', '«', 'Steppenwolf', '»', 'nannten', '.']]
```

Now, I need so select all lists within the list of lists that contain any of the strings listed here:

```
vds_nennen = ['nennen', 'nenne', 'nennst', 'nennt', 'nenne', 'nennest', 'nannte', 
'nanntest', 'nannten', 'nanntet', 'nennte', 'nenntest', 'nennten', 'nenntet', 'genannt']
```

So the desired output is:

```
[['Dieses', 'Buch', 'enthält', 'die', 'uns', 'geblichenen', 'Aufzeichnungen', 
'jenes', 'Mannes', ',', 'welchen', 'wir', 'mit', 'einem', 'Ausdruck', ',', 'den',
'er', 'selbst', 'mehrmals', 'gebrauchte', ',', 'den', '«', 'Steppenwolf', '»', 
'nannten', '.']]
```

(because the last list in the list of lists contains `'nannten'` that `vds_nennen` list also has)

I tried to loop over the list `vds_nennen` this way:

```
[[t[0] for t in tagger.tag(s)] for s in corpus.sents()[:5] if [vds for vds in vds_nennen] in s]
```

But got nothing:

```
[]
```

Sorry in advance for my ignorance in looping... Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the `if` expression to use `any`:

```
[[t[0] for t in tagger.tag(s)] for s in corpus.sents()[:5] if any([vds in s for vds in vds_nennen])]
```

You can also postprocess your original list (call it `tt`) e.g.

```
[t for t in tt if any([vds in t for vds in vds_nennen])]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution returns ```[[], [], [], [], ['nannten']]```, so: 1. It returns all lists (that to not match the condition), but makes them empty and 2. It reduces the lists that match the condition to the single string, what is very different from the desired output...

Comment: @Gavrk I misinterpreted your original code; I think you do need to leave the `if` clause where it was and just rewrite it to use any. See my edit.